# How to Share a document with Read Permission Level?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

We are creating SharePoint Groups right now, and we have a lot of people in a group called Readers with the Read Permission Level. I have noticed that they are unable to share documents. When they click on the ellipses and click "Share" we get this message

[image]

I have noticed that the only way to get this functionality is if you have full control permission.

Is there anyway around this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the way I would get around this is assign an administrator (really Edit Rights) to a power user that will use this the most, or someone that is a SharePoint savvy user. Also, make it known on SharePoint that "User A" has the keys to that document library. That way it falls out of your hands, and gives the users drive to use the company's intranet/extranet.

Any person that needs access to the document library has to send a request to "User A" in order for him/her to grant access to that user. A workflow can even be set up if you want to be fancy, that will allow a user to fill out a form of the document library that he/she is trying to access, and will email the correct person in charge of granting rights.

Comment: Unfortunately this creates overhead on "User A", I suppose what we are looking for is a 1-click step to literally share a document with somebody (assuming they have rights to view it), apparently this functionality was available in SharePoint 2010 with the "email button" but seems to be missing in SP 2013.

Comment: You could create a workflow that users could fill out who they want to share it with and the workflow will grant the user permissions in an impersonation step.

Answer (score 0):

this is default behavior. two things you can do it.

- Create the another permission level copied from Read Permissions level and add **Manage Permissions**. this will allow the user to share the doucments but it will give them the ability to share withfull control.
- other way is enable the "allowing the Access Requests" will be the best options.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/72ca5f71-1826-4056-b506-a30b5b99adca/only-a-limited-set-of-people-are-allowed-to-share-this-content-sharepoint-2013

Comment: Don't edit the OOB Read Permission level, copy the permission level first to make a custom permission level.

Comment: Waqas, we do not want to give our users full control. We want them to have read permission level,but we want them to have the convenience of sharing a document with person x, if person x has access to the document as well.

Comment: then their is no way a read permission guy can share the docs...other than that as i mentioned you can think about access request